# SQL: Get count of distinct values of the table

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to get the count of distinct value of the table for example 
I have below records in a table :

```
PK  Value
1       A
2       A
3       A
4       B
5       C
6       C
7       D
8       D
9       D
10      D
11      E
12      F
```

Looking above there are primary key`(PK)` and values, I want result like below :

```
Value   Count
A        3
B        1
C        2
D        4
E        1
F        1
```

Which should do a count each of the values.

I am trying the `count(value)` function but not getting the expected result, is there any other function can be used?

Comment: ... `COUNT(*)` is the ways to do this.  What statement are you using, and what results is it giving you?

Answer (score 2):

```
select value, count(*)
from the_table
group by value
order by value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Value, count(Value) AS Count,
FROM table
Group BY Value
```